# How can I make a non-layered feed forward NN in pytorch?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I want to set up a network that may have lots of complicated skip connections, but will still be feed forward (no recurrent connections). Each node will still be a "classic" node in the sense that it will just have a weight for each connection, and then multiply each weight by the corresponding input, sum them, and put it through a nonlinear function.

For example, it might look like this:

[image]

However, I don't think I can easily use something like the `nn.Linear` module to calculate outputs, because (in the picture for example), the red nodes get inputs from the green nodes *and* the pink nodes, but the green nodes also need the pink nodes' outputs to calculate.

I can think of some ways to do this, but they're real ugly and pytorch usually has a smart way of doing things. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: You might want to look at [torch.sparse](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html).